# How to set navigation bar background image for all devices including iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I am trying set background image for the navigation bar. It's working for all other devices, but in iPhone X its not working due to increased size.

Comment: "Not working"...how? give us some details. How is it not working?

Answer (score 9):

Use this code :

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navbar background").resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 ,right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to stretch vertically your image, just use 2 background images, one for all devices and one for iPhone X (if your app work both in portrait and landscape you have to use more than 2....):

ObjC:

```
if (MAX([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) == 812.0) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar_X.png"]
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
else
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Swift:

```
if max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) == 812.0 {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBar_X.png"), for: .default)
    }
    else {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBar.png"), for: .default)
    }
```

If your image looks good stretched vertically:

ObjC:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Swift:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBar.png")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 ,right: 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```